# Asp classic 3.0 loop and movenext

Tags: loops, asp-classic

I have problem with this Asp Classic 3.0 code.

I need send email message when the sql query found in database table the records with :

```
SQL = " SELECT * FROM doTable Where div = 1; "
```

And I have tried this Asp code:

```
   SQL = " SELECT * FROM doTable Where div = 1; "

   Set Rec = createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   Rec.open SQL, cn

   If not Rec.eof then

   msg = msg & VBcrlf & "<br />Records founds!<br />"

   Do while not Rec.eof 

   msg = msg & VBcrlf & "ID record: " & Rec("Id") & ""         

   msg = ""

   Rec.moveNext()      
   Loop       

   Else

   msg = msg & VBcrlf & "<br />No records!<br />"

   End If

   Rec.close()
   set Rec = nothing    

   cn.close()
   set cn = nothing
```

The problem is this part of code:

```
msg = ""
```

If I have found records and the **msg = ""** is present in code the output of msg is empty; if the **msg = ""** is not present in code the output is:

```
Records founds!
ID record: 32
Records founds!
ID record: 61
Records founds!
ID record: 77
```

Why can not I get this output ?

```
Records founds!
ID record: 32
ID record: 61
ID record: 77
```

Can you help me?
Thank you in advance-

**EDIT**

```
With objMessage 
    .From     = RS("Email_from")
    .To       = RS("Email_to")
    .Subject  = "Alert div"
    .HtmlBody = msg
    .Fields("urn:schemas:httpmail:importance").Value = 2 
    .Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:X-MSMail-Priority") = 6
    .Fields.Update()    

on error resume next
   .Send
    if Err.Number <> 0 then
       response.Write "Email send failed # : " & Err.Number & " -  " & Err.Description & ".<br />"&vbcrlf
    end if  

End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
msg = msg & VBcrlf & "ID record: " & Rec("Id") & ""         

msg = ""
```

This code doesn't make sense, `msg = ""` changes the value of msg to an empty string, and makes the previous line pointless.  It would make more sense to have `msg = ""` before you start looping through your recordset.

Try this

```
SQL = " SELECT * FROM doTable Where div = 1; "

msg = ""

msg = msg & VBcrlf & "<br />Records founds!<br />"


   Set Rec = server.createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   Rec.open SQL, cn

   If Rec.eof and rec.bof then

   msg = "<br />No records!<br />"

   else

   Do while not Rec.eof 

   msg = msg & VBcrlf & "ID record: " & Rec("Id") & ""         

   Rec.moveNext     
   Loop       

   End If

   Rec.close
   set Rec = nothing    

   cn.close
   set cn = nothing
```

Comment: In this way the string "Records founds!" always appear, if there's not record too.

Comment: @FabioPellerito - I don't think so.  `msg = "<br />No records!<br />"` should overwrite "Records Found" if the recordset is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Rec.recordcount and can be used like this:

```
Set Rec = server.createObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Rec.open SQL, cn
somevar=Rec.recordcount
```

Then somevar can be used for display like this:

```
There are <%=somevar%> records.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code is correct. Where is the rige to output the variabile **msg**?

```
Records founds!
ID record: 32
Records founds!
ID record: 61
Records founds!
ID record: 77
```

Maybe it's the output of 3 query?

Comment: Not ... is output of 1 query... in first question **EDIT** I have posted the variable msg, thank you

Comment: I would like to understand where you put the line of code for sending email. In or out of the loop.